# Calculating and correcting bit errors using Hidden Markov Model in C++

Tags: c++

I am a student and new to C++. It would be great if somebody could help me write a program. Here is what it is suppose to do;

1- generates a Pseudo Random Bit Sequence (PN9 or PN15) 9 or 15 bit length. 
2- saves the bit sequence from step 1 into a bit array/buffer and displays the array.
3- calculates the transition probabilities for 
   1.   0 --> 0
   2.   0 --> 1
   3.   1 --> 0
   4.   1 --> 1
4- asks the user to input a bit sequence
5- introduces some noise.. i.e. flips some of the input bits 
6- calculates and corrects the BIT errors based on the transition probabilities calculated in step-3

can any body guide or share his work with me on this?

Comment: What exactly do you expect from us? present you code that does what you want?

Comment: No i will not do your homework for you. Try coding something and then askingu us specifics about your doubts.

Comment: SigLib http://www.numerix.co.uk/siglib.html has PN9 and PN15 sequence generators in C which could be adapted for your purpose.

Comment: I have used bitset library function to create bits but I don't know how to put them in an array and what library function will test each bit in the array for True or False Values. Sorry I am having difficulties to post my code in the comments.

Comment: srand((unsigned)time(0));unsigned int x;
   unsigned char array[512];
     for (int i=0; i<=511 ; i++)
    {
   x=rand()% 512;
      bitset<9> bits(x);  
     for (int i=0; i<=511 ; i++)
    {
  x=rand()% 512; bitset<9> bits(x); std::cout << bits ;
         array[i]=bits;
The last statement gives the error " Error E2034 : Cannot convert 'bitset<9>' to 'unsigned char' in function main()..... please let me know what is going wrong. Also how i would access individual bits to test them for their value 1/0 (true/false).

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find many of the functions in the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) useful for your work. Apart from that, you'll have to do some work and then ask a specific question to get guidance.